# Java don't run the main file (classpath)

Tags: java, class, package, classpath

Hello guys i'm new with java and i'm starting to work with packages etc, i have a problem when i try to run my main file located at

```
C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\Java\latebd\Test.Java
```

When i run

```
java -cp C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\Java\latebd\latebd.Test
```

instead of having the code running i get this (it's in italian bu basically it's telling all the options when i use java -

[image]

Why do i get that?

Comment: Have you compiled the file?

Comment: A classpath must not point to a single class.  Each entry in a classpath must be a .jar file, or a directory containing compiled packages.  If your source code contains `package latebd;` then you should be running `java -cp C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\Java latebd.Test`.  Notice that the classpath by itself is not enough;  `-cp` and its argument tell Java where to find classes, but you must still tell Java exactly which class to run, by specifying the main class name (not a file name) as an argument which does not follow any options.

Answer (score 1):

1. you need to compile it e.g. `javac C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\Java\latebd\*`
2. provide the path where it's already compiled as a classpath, and to run it use `java -cp "C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\Java\latebd\*" latebd.Test`

Answer (score 0):

Try `java -cp "C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\Java\latebd\latebd.Test"`